# CreativeDream/php-uploader 'replace' => false, //Replace the file if it already exists {Boolean} is not working

Tags: php

```
<?php
    include('../../../php/class.uploader.php');

    $uploader = new Uploader();
    $data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
        'limit' => null, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
        'maxSize' => 10, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
        'extensions' => null, //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
        'required' => true, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
        'uploadDir' => '../../../uploads/', //Upload directory {String}
        'title' => array('name'), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
        'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
        'replace' => true, //Replace the file if it already exists  {Boolean}
        'perms' => null, //Uploaded file permisions {null, Number}
        'onCheck' => null, //A callback function name to be called by checking a file for errors (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onError' => null, //A callback function name to be called if an error occured (must return an array) | ($errors, $file) | Callback
        'onSuccess' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded | ($files, $metas) | Callback
        'onUpload' => null, //A callback function name to be called if all files were successfully uploaded (must return an array) | ($file) | Callback
        'onComplete' => null, //A callback function name to be called when upload is complete | ($file) | Callback
        'onRemove' => null //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
    ));

    if($data['isComplete']){
        $files = $data['data'];

        echo json_encode($files['metas'][0]['name']);
    }

    if($data['hasErrors']){
        $errors = $data['errors'];
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }

    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should. Try to update php-uploader to 0.4 version. Don't forget that on frontend you will need another option:

```
alloDuplicates: true //or false
```